# How can I examine Perl objects (PML nodes)?

Tags: perl, oop

How can I introspect a tree of [`Treex::PML::Node`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Treex-PML/lib/Treex/PML/Node.pm) objects to find out the data each node contains? I can call the root node's methods: E.g., `$root->firstson()` is another `Node` object. But how do I inspect the data fields of the tree nodes? I know too little about Perl objects to crack this nut.

Background: I am wrestling with an application that supports Perl scripting, and trying to manipulate a parsed sentence exposed as a tree of PML Nodes. (Each node represents a word and its various annotations, which is what I'm trying to access.) Unfortunately I do not have access to the PML schema-- all I have is the handle to the `$root` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `attribute_paths` method of the Node object to get a list of what data is available.

Go to [Prague Markup Language Documentation](http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/jazz/PML/doc/) and download ALL of the example schemas (they refer to each other...)

```
example1.xml
example1_schema.xml
example2.xml
example2_schema.xml
...
```

In this example, I am using `example7.xml` to get a list of paths, which you can use to get at the data.  The data stored in the PML Nodes come from the following
sentences:

> **John loves Mary.  He told her this Friday.**

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Treex::PML;

my $document = Treex::PML::Factory->createDocumentFromFile('example7.xml');

foreach my $tree ($document->trees) {
    my $node = $tree;
    while ($node) {
        $node = $node->following; # depth-first traversal
        my @paths = $node->attribute_paths();
        print "Can call the following:\n";
        for (@paths) {
            print '$node->all("' . $_ . '");' . "\n";
            my ($value) = $node->all($_);
            print " ==> $value\n";
        }
        exit 0;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Can call the following:
$node->all("label");
 ==> NP
$node->all("w/id");
 ==> t#s1w1
$node->all("w/#content");
 ==> John
```

Comment: Thanks! Only saw this now, for some reason.